# A clarification in Signature schemes for Strong Unforgeability.

Tags: cr.crypto-security, cryptographic-attack

Signature scheme is strongly unforgeable. 
"making the message m being signed depend on the randomness r — we break
the proof of security for the underlying signature."

From Paper: Strongly Unforgeable Signatures Based on Computational Diffie-Hellman - Dan Boneh, Emily Shen, and Brent Waters.

Can some one point out how a scheme can be broken when the message being signed depends on the randomness?

Thanks. Please let me know if I am not clear. The paper has it all.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [A digital signature scheme secure against adaptive chosen-message attacks](http://en.scientificcommons.org/43510384).

Answer (score 1):

Their comment was not meant to apply to all signature schemes, just the specific construction they are talking about in that paragraph. (Also, it was not meant as a formal statement; it was just mentioned as part of the intuition for their construction.)